# SherlockListFragment setRetainInstance(true) doesn't work as expected

Tags: android

I use `setRetainInstance(true)` on `SherlockListFragment`, and expect it to not destroy and re-create itself during screen rotation. However, it doesn't. It still calling `onActivityCreated` each time I perform rotation.

### WatchlistFragment.java

```
package org.yccheok.jstock.gui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

public class WatchlistFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "WatchlistFragment onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "WatchlistFragment onActivityCreated");

        // Not sure why. After I setRetainInstance to true, onActivityCreated is still
        // called for each screen rotation changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getTimeConsumingData()));
    }

    public String[] getTimeConsumingData() {
        Log.i(TAG, "WatchlistFragment getTimeConsumingData");
        return new String[] { "A", "B", "C"};
    }

    private static final String TAG = WatchlistFragment.class.getSimpleName();
}
```

### JStockFragmentActivity.java

```
package org.yccheok.jstock.gui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class JStockFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "JStockFragmentActivity onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.jstock_fragment_activity);
    }

    private static final String TAG = JStockFragmentActivity.class.getSimpleName();
}
```

### jstock_fragment_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment class="org.yccheok.jstock.gui.WatchlistFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting the following logcat for each rotation

```
02-25 20:11:10.562: I/JStockFragmentActivity(6989): JStockFragmentActivity onCreate
02-25 20:11:10.597: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment onCreate
02-25 20:11:10.613: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment onActivityCreated
02-25 20:11:10.613: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment getTimeConsumingData
02-25 20:11:12.078: I/JStockFragmentActivity(6989): JStockFragmentActivity onCreate
02-25 20:11:12.109: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment onCreate
02-25 20:11:12.121: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment onActivityCreated
02-25 20:11:12.121: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment getTimeConsumingData
02-25 20:11:17.492: I/JStockFragmentActivity(6989): JStockFragmentActivity onCreate
02-25 20:11:17.519: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment onCreate
02-25 20:11:17.527: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment onActivityCreated
02-25 20:11:17.527: I/WatchlistFragment(6989): WatchlistFragment getTimeConsumingData
```

I thought having `setRetainInstance(true)` shall not create `WatchlistFragment` again and again during rotation?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct accoding to [the specs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29):

> - `onDestroy()` will not be called (but `onDetach()` still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
> - `onCreate(Bundle)` will not be called since the fragment is not being re-created.
> - `onAttach(Activity)` and **`onActivityCreated(Bundle)` will still be called**.

Comment: onCreate is still being called multiple times

Comment: Yeah, right - my fault. Didn't read your log completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it calls `onActivityCreated()` but it doesn't call `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`. So move your code which you don't want to be called again to `onCreate()`.

Comment: onCreate is still being called multiple times

Comment: You can try to move 'setRetainInstance(true);' to your onCreate(). I always put it there and it works fine.